# Fragment and BackStack not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

My MainActivity contains a Navigation Drawer with two fragments. The first fragment is loaded automatically when the app starts. I want the app to switch from fragment two to fragment one when the back button is pressed or if the first fragment is added then exit the app. I am adding the fragmentTransaction of the first fragment to a stack and then calling `popBackStack` in my `onBackPressed` method. However the behaviour is pretty weird.

When I'm on the first fragment the application should exit (ie, execute super.onBackPressed) however when on the first fragment and pressing back the first fragment is removed from the fragmentholder leading to a blank screen and then on pressing the second time the app closes.

When I'm on the second fragment nothing happens when the back button is pressed the first time and on pressing the back button a second time the app closes. Here's the relevant code from the MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (musicService.isPng()) moveTaskToBack(true);

        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack("returnFragment", 0);

        else super.onBackPressed();
    }


private void loadSelection(int i) {
        navList.setItemChecked(i, true);

        switch (i) {

            case 0:
                FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, firstFragment)
                        .addToBackStack("returnFragment")
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 1:
                SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, secondFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 2:
                musicService.removeNotification();
                musicService.stopSelf();
                MainActivity.this.finish();
        }

    }
```

loadSelection(0) is called in the `onCreate` of the MainActivity

Unlike given in the code, I have tried various modes of implementing the `popBackStack()` method but all of them lead to the same result. Just to add I don't want to implement a workaround since there are only 2 fragments since I am already working on adding new fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,
call method .addToBackStack("returnFragment") while loading second fragment and remove it from first transaction.

Comment: Alright this works! Seems it only reverses the transaction and not the fragment itself.